# xlform custom rows using nibs

Tags: ios, forms, xlform

I want to use `XLFormSelectorCell` but I need to customize the UI in a nib file. How do I do this? Can I just create a subclass from `XLFormSelectorCell` instead of `XLFormBaseCell` or do I really need to rewrite all the methods in `XLFormSelectorCell`? Can you show me the best way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly mentioned with example in this [link](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm/tree/master/Examples/Objective-C/Examples/Others/CustomCells).

All you need to do is just create a custom cell of type XLFormBaseCell and then manipulate the data according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

In the overridden `+load` method of your custom cell, you need to add your cell in the `XLFormViewController.cellClassesForRowDescriptorTypes` dictionary. But, when using nibs, instead of the class, you should use a string containing the nibName.

For example:

```
[XLFormViewController.cellClassesForRowDescriptorTypes setObject:@"nibName" forKey:@"XLFormRowDescriptorYourCustomType"]
```